# How to style multiple div classes

Tags: html, css

I am looking for how I can apply a single style to multiple div classes on CSS by giving them d same width, height and margin

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Page title</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="landing page">
  <div class="box 1"></div>
  <div class="box 2"></div>
  <div class="box 3"></div>
  <div class="box 4"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box">/div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

 .landing page{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
 }

 .box 1, box 2, box 3{
   width: 30%;
   height: 15vh;
   margin: 2px;
  }
```

But I want to also add a style to a two div classes in CSS by adding a 2px yellow border so they stands out from d rest. For example

CSS

```
.box1 .boxes{
     border: 2px yellow solid;
   }
```

Comment: I didn't understand your second question

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces from your class names, or else they will be treated as separate classes.

```css
/* All elements with class="box" */
.box {
  background: pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.box1 {
  border: 2px yellow solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="landingpage">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
  <div class="box box4"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add same class to all `div`

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">/div>
```

and style them this way

```
.box {
  // your styles
}
```

If you want the yellow border to be added to specific divs, just create a class for it.

```
<div class="box yellow-border">/div>
```

and in css

```
.yellow-border {
    border: 2px yellow solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can use the :nth-child() property like that ( I have commented the code so you can understand).

You can go to that site to learn more about it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

 .landing page{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
 }

 .box{
   width: 30%;
   height: 15vh;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color:black;
   
  }
  
/* Will affect the element 3 */
.box:nth-child(3){
     border: 2px yellow solid;
}

/* Will affect the element 5 and all following elements 3 */
.box:nth-child(n+5){
     border: 2px yellow solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Page title</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="landing-page">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```